# App not can't run in samsung dex

Tags: android, samsung-dex

I developed an android app and tried to run it on Samsung Dex. However, when I tried to launch my app, a toast will show as below:

> *** can't run in Samsung Dex. It's designed for phone touch screens.

I checked the guidance [here](https://developer.samsung.com/samsung-dex/modify-optimizing), and found these settings

```
<uses-configuration android:reqTouchScreen="finger">
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen">
<android:required="true">
```

will prevent apps running in Dex. However, I didn't add any of these in my `AndroidManifest.xml`. Is there anyone who has same issues with me or knows the solution? Thanks.

Comment: "However, I didn't add any of these in my `AndroidManifest.xml.`" I'd recommend double-checking the _merged_ manifest to verify that none of the libraries your app depends on introduced the elements in your question without you knowing.

Comment: Thanks @stkent for your recommendation. I dumped the manifest file in the apk and found `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen">` there. Actually a library in my project will declare this feature as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to suggestion of @stkent. I double checked libraries referenced in my project. And I found related settings in one of them. Just removing the setting and repacking the aar will resolve the issue.